# Margin or Padding in CSS unexpected behavior

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to recreate a `CSS` sheet to improve my skills with `CSS`. However there is a small spacing problem between tapered-line and h4 (armor class) and I can not figure out why it is happening. The `CSS` I'm atempting to recreate is http://valloric.github.io/statblock5e/demo.html
it is not a big problem but id still like to know what I'm missing. in the hope of improving my understanding of CSS.
Thank you in advance for any help.

this is the `HTML` and the `CSS` I have so far

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
stat-block {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bar {
    height: 5px;
    background: #E69A28;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

content {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Myriad Pro', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    background: #FDF1DC;
    padding: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    border: 1px #DDD solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em #867453;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-columns: 400px;
    -moz-columns: 400px;
    columns: 400px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-fill: auto;
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', 'Lora', 'Calisto MT', 'Bookman Old Style', Bookman, 'Goudy Old Style', Garamond, 'Hoefler Text', 'Bitstream Charter', Georgia, serif;
    color: #7A200D;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}

    svg {
      fill: #922610;
      stroke: #922610;
      margin-top: 0.6em;
      margin-bottom: 0.35em;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
    }

   property-line{
    color: #7A200D;
}

property-line {
    line-height: 1.4;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

property-line > h4 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: bold;
}

property-line > p:first-of-type {
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 0;
}
property-line > p {
    text-indent: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}
abilities-block{
        font-size: 13.5px;
}
table {
    color: #7A200D;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
th, td {
    font-size: 13.5px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
property-block {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: block;
}

property-block > h4{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

property-block > p:first-of-type {
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 0;
}
property-block > p {
    text-indent: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}

h3{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7A200D;
    color: #7A200D;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    break-after: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <stat-block>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <content>
            <div class="stat-block">
                <creature-heading>
                    <h1>Animated Armor</h1>
                    <h2>Medium construct, unaligned</h2>
                </creature-heading>
                <tapered-rule>
                    <svg height="5" width="400">
                        <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                    </svg>
                </tapered-rule>
                <top-stats>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Armor Class</h4>
                        <p>18 (natural armor)</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Hit Points</h4>
                        <p>33 (6d8 + 6)</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Speed</h4>
                        <p>25ft</p>
                    </property-line <tapered-rule>
                    <svg height="5" width="400">
                        <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                    </svg>
                    </tapered-rule>
                    <abilities-block>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>STR</th>
                                    <th>DEX</th>
                                    <th>CON</th>
                                    <th>INT</th>
                                    <th>WIS</th>
                                    <th>CHA</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="str">14 (+2)</td>
                                    <td id="dex">11 (+0)</td>
                                    <td id="con">13 (+1)</td>
                                    <td id="int">1 (–5)</td>
                                    <td id="wis">3 (–4)</td>
                                    <td id="cha">1 (–5)</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </abilities-block>
                    <tapered-rule>
                        <svg height="5" width="400">
                            <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                        </svg>
                    </tapered-rule>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Damage Immunities</h4>
                        <p>poison, psychic</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Condition Immunities</h4>
                        <p>blinded, charmed, deafened, exhaustion, frightened, paralyzed, petrified, poisoned</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Senses</h4>
                        <p>blindsight 60 ft. (blind beyond this radius), passive Perception 6</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Languages</h4>
                        <p>—</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Challenge</h4>
                        <p>1 (200 XP)</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <tapered-rule>
                        <svg height="5" width="400">
                            <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                        </svg>
                    </tapered-rule>
                    <property-block>
                        <h4>Antimagic Susceptibility.</h4>
                        <p>The armor is incapacitated while in the area of an <i>antimagic
      field</i>. If targeted by <i>dispel magic</i>, the armor must succeed on a Constitution saving throw against the caster’s
                            spell save DC or fall unconscious for 1 minute.</p>
                    </property-block>
                    <property-block>
                        <h4>False Appearance.</h4>
                        <p>While the armor remains motionless, it is indistinguishable from a normal suit of armor.</p>
                    </property-block>
                    <h3>Actions</h3>

                    <property-block>
                        <h4>Multiattack.</h4>
                        <p>The armor makes two melee attacks.</p>
                    </property-block>

                    <property-block>
                        <h4>Slam.</h4>
                        <p><i>Melee Weapon Attack:</i> +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target.
                            <i>Hit:</i> 5 (1d6 + 2) bludgeoning damage.</p>
                    </property-block>
            </div>
        </content>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </stat-block>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: It would be useful if the demo did not use html imports, these are not widely supported yet

Comment: I really don't understand the use of non-semantic (custom) HTML-elements. There is absolutely nothing in that demo that couldn't be done by using simple `<div>`s.

Comment: @DarrenH this is why i am atempting to recreate the demo using  simple CSS.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie i understand the demo seams to be over complicated just to be over complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your `HTML` code ,you declared one  tag inside

other but it's not possible in `html`.

I'm specifying that part of your code here

```
**</property-line <tapered-rule>**
                    <svg height="5" width="400">
                        <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                     </svg>
                     </tapered-rule>
```

probably you did that accidentally but that was the cause this problem.I'm added an edited snippet below.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
stat-block {
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bar {
    height: 5px;
    background: #E69A28;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

content {
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Myriad Pro', Calibri, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13.5px;
    background: #FDF1DC;
    padding: 0.6em;
    padding-bottom: 0.5em;
    border: 1px #DDD solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em #867453;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    width: 400px;
    -webkit-columns: 400px;
    -moz-columns: 400px;
    columns: 400px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-gap: 40px;
    column-gap: 40px;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
    -moz-column-fill: auto;
    column-fill: auto;
    display: block;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', 'Lora', 'Calisto MT', 'Bookman Old Style', Bookman, 'Goudy Old Style', Garamond, 'Hoefler Text', 'Bitstream Charter', Georgia, serif;
    color: #7A200D;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

h2 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0;
}

    svg {
      fill: #922610;
      stroke: #922610;
      margin-top: 0.6em;
      margin-bottom: 0.35em;
    transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px;
    }

   property-line{
    color: #7A200D;
}

property-line {
    line-height: 1.4;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -1em;
    padding-left: 1em;
}

property-line > h4 {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: bold;
}

property-line > p:first-of-type {
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 0;
}
property-line > p {
    text-indent: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}
abilities-block{
        font-size: 13.5px;
}
table {
    color: #7A200D;
    width: 100%;
    border: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tbody {
    display: table-row-group;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-color: inherit;
}
th, td {
    font-size: 13.5px;
    width: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
property-block {
    margin-top: 0.3em;
    margin-bottom: 0.9em;
    line-height: 1.5;
    display: block;
}

property-block > h4{
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

property-block > p:first-of-type {
    display: inline;
    text-indent: 0;
}
property-block > p {
    text-indent: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}

h3{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #7A200D;
    color: #7A200D;
    font-size: 21px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: normal;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.3em;
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    break-after: avoid-column;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <stat-block>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <content>
            <div class="stat-block">
                <creature-heading>
                    <h1>Animated Armor</h1>
                    <h2>Medium construct, unaligned</h2>
                </creature-heading>
                <tapered-rule>
                    <svg height="5" width="400">
                        <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                    </svg>
                </tapered-rule>
                <top-stats>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Armor Class</h4>
                        <p>18 (natural armor)</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Hit Points</h4>
                        <p>33 (6d8 + 6)</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Speed</h4>
                        <p>25ft</p>
                    </property-line >
                  <tapered-rule>
                    <svg height="5" width="400">
                        <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                    </svg>
                    </tapered-rule>
                    <abilities-block>
                        <table>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>STR</th>
                                    <th>DEX</th>
                                    <th>CON</th>
                                    <th>INT</th>
                                    <th>WIS</th>
                                    <th>CHA</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="str">14 (+2)</td>
                                    <td id="dex">11 (+0)</td>
                                    <td id="con">13 (+1)</td>
                                    <td id="int">1 (–5)</td>
                                    <td id="wis">3 (–4)</td>
                                    <td id="cha">1 (–5)</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </abilities-block>
                    <tapered-rule>
                        <svg height="5" width="400">
                            <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                        </svg>
                    </tapered-rule>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Damage Immunities</h4>
                        <p>poison, psychic</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Condition Immunities</h4>
                        <p>blinded, charmed, deafened, exhaustion, frightened, paralyzed, petrified, poisoned</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Senses</h4>
                        <p>blindsight 60 ft. (blind beyond this radius), passive Perception 6</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Languages</h4>
                        <p>—</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <property-line>
                        <h4>Challenge</h4>
                        <p>1 (200 XP)</p>
                    </property-line>
                    <tapered-rule>
                        <svg height="5" width="400">
                            <polyline points="0,0 400,2.5 0,5"></polyline>
                        </svg>
                    </tapered-rule>
                    <property-block>
                        <h4>Antimagic Susceptibility.</h4>
                        <p>The armor is incapacitated while in the area of an <i>antimagic
      field</i>. If targeted by <i>dispel magic</i>, the armor must succeed on a Constitution saving throw against the caster’s
                            spell save DC or fall unconscious for 1 minute.</p>
                    </property-block>
                    <property-block>
                        <h4>False Appearance.</h4>
                        <p>While the armor remains motionless, it is indistinguishable from a normal suit of armor.</p>
                    </property-block>
                    <h3>Actions</h3>

                    <property-block>
                        <h4>Multiattack.</h4>
                        <p>The armor makes two melee attacks.</p>
                    </property-block>

                    <property-block>
                        <h4>Slam.</h4>
                        <p><i>Melee Weapon Attack:</i> +4 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target.
                            <i>Hit:</i> 5 (1d6 + 2) bludgeoning damage.</p>
                    </property-block>
            </div>
        </content>
        <div class="bar"></div>
    </stat-block>
</body>
```

Comment: why you guys down voted? I'm created the output he requested,and specifies the problem with his code

Comment: I also don't understand the reason of downvoting. This answer point to an actual error in the OP's markup that led to wrong nesting of elements because the opening tag would be ignored.

Comment: That is a problem that i did not spot so thank you for pointing it out, however it is not the reason of the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @dreamhunter looking into the change that you made the spacing looks to be fix in the snippet that you made however that seams to be from the change in font.

Comment: @may19c19 what is the current problem you need to be fixed?

Comment: @dreamhunter the spacing between the tapered-line and h4 (armor class) on mine is not the same as the spacing on the demo. id like to identify why this is. your snippet changed the font and that fixed the problem but i am using the same font this is used in the demo.

Comment: @may19c19 i can't find out any difference there ,what do you feeling margin is less or margin is high when compared with demo.

Comment: @dreamhunter iv added an image to the OP that shows the spacing that i am talking about